# Inappropriate 'unchecked assignment' warning in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, gxt, unchecked-cast

I have a line saying

```
List<FilterConfig> configs = filter.getFilterConfig();
```

and IntelliJ warns me about

```
Unchecked assignment: java.util.List to java.util.List<com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.FilterConfig>
```

However, the called method says:

```
public abstract List<FilterConfig> getFilterConfig();
```

so I do not see any unchecked cast here.

https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/filters/Filter.html
https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/FilterConfig.html

Comment: Noting the plain `java.util.List`, do you have a raw type somewhere? Raw types have a somewhat viral effect: once you've got a raw type somewhere (including, but not limited to, `extends MyGenericType` (without the generics)), a lot of things that look like they should be non-raw are considered raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andy, I've found the problem: `filter` was a raw type here but I thought this should not affect `getFilterConfig()`.

As soon as I changed

```
Filter filter
```

to

```
Filter<?,?> filter
```

the warning disappeared.

Comment: Glad you worked it out!